# Download file after clicking hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kH0T.png)After clicking this hyperlink, internet explorer pops up and then automatically downloads an excel file. How can I get it to automatically download the file and then save to a folder?

What I have now saves the webpage to the folder, not the downloaded file.

```
Sub SaveSpreads()


Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://www.citivelocity.com/analytics/chartingreport?user=cfok&dist=excel&jobid=352106&runid=1919430&includeCharts=true&hash=b5136b4028"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\Users\U708699\Desktop\Citi\CitiSpreads.csv")
oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
 Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub test()
    DownloadFile$ = "batchReport.xls" 'here the name with extension from 
    URL$ = "https://www.citivelocity.com/analytics/chartingreport?user=cfok&dist=excel&jobid=352106&runid=1919430&includeCharts=true&hash=b5136b4028" & DownloadFile 'Here is the web address
    LocalFilename$ = "C:\Users\U708699\Desktop\Citi\CitiSpreads.csv" 'here the drive and download directory
    MsgBox "Download Status : " & URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0) = 0
End Sub
```

add a reference to `Microsoft WinHTTP Services`. In your code you can change the `URL` to target the excel file directly. Please check the code behind URL in web page.

Comment: Hi arun, I just tried that code and it didn't work. I added the reference and ran the code but nothing happens

Comment: share your `HTML` code behind the url from web page also mention the url you tried to access through macro

Comment: <html><head></head><body></body></html>​
<body></body>​
The page is blank, it just starts a download. When I navigate to https://www.citivelocity.com/analytics/chartingreport?user=cfok&dist=excel&jobid=352106&runid=1920829&includeCharts=true&hash=b5136b4028 it just pops up a box that says "what do you want to do with batchReport.xls? Open Save Cancel

Comment: I cannot log in to the url, asking for log in credentials, please  share the `HTML` behind the hyperlink you are clicking, we can understand the Java post back action behind the action

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body></body></html>

This is it, it is literally a blank webpage just used to download the file.

Comment: right click on webpage select `inspect element` place the cursor in the hyperlink and click then @ `DOM explorer` you can get the code

Comment: I believe you are getting blank webpage after clicking on hyper link, please do inspect element before clicking hyper link also share the url in browser once you click hyperlink

Comment: The hyperlink is sent to me in an email. I included a picture in the post of what I see when I click on the hyperlink. In my outlook I cannot inspect the hyperlink

Comment: Please try updated answer, its hard to provide solution without webpage code

Comment: The picture I included shows the code, there are only like three lines of code

Comment: Hi arun, no luck there. It does not download the popup excel file

Comment: This will be helpful to you <https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8099c4f9-4383-4c63-a96f-f5d5aa8c8e19/vba-to-download-a-file-without-a-direct-url?forum=isvvba>